# How to set mobaxterm to factory settings?

Tags: ssh, sftp, mobaxterm

I have been using mobaxterm for ssh connection to a ubuntu server to compile and run C programs. I use the sftp settings to edit code on the fly with its built in text editor. Everything was great until one day, the sftp directory opened a directory so high up I did not have access to its children. I tired installing and reinstalling the application but then I was still returned to my old settings. I want to make mobaxterm have like a factory reset so that I can get it to work like it did in the very beginning.